# How can I pass a variable/argument into this sed script that I am testing?

Tags: sed

I want to be able to pass in $1 into this command that I am running, but I think it is trying it literally as opposed to using the value of $1:

find /test/$1 -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i -r 's/href="http://$1//href="//g'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; single quotes prevent variable expansion.  You need to use double quotes, *but* because you are also using them literally we need to switch quoting styles mid-stream.  And I'm unclear as to how you expected slashes to work simultaneously as regex delimiters and data:

```
find "/test/$1" -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i -r 's,href="http://'"$1"'/,href="/,g'
```

You will also need to watch out that `$1` doesn't contain any regex special characters, and if it might contain a comma then you will probably want to use something else as the regex delimiter.